# How to remove last line in a text file in R?

Tags: r

Im reading a text file containing data with "problematic" line. The last line that starts with *NOTE has to be removed (number of rows in the text file is not always the same):

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
A2  17  14
B2  20  -1
C2  21  36

*NOTE: -1 = data do not exist
```

This is my line to read the text file (i have to select text file since its location not constant:

```
my_data <- read.delim(file.choose(), header = TRUE, sep = "", quote = "",
                      dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "")
```

I have tried :

```
my_data[- grep("*NOTE:", my_data$ColumnA),]
```

But it does not seem to work.
Any simple solutions to this?

Comment: You have to escape the special characters in your regex or use `fixed = TRUE`. i.e. : `my_data[- grep("*NOTE:", my_data$ColumnA, fixed=TRUE),]`

Comment: this command my_data[- grep("*NOTE:", my_data$ColumnA, fixed=TRUE),] returns: "data frame with 0 columns and 59 rows"

Comment: Escaping the special character `*` would be `"^\\*NOTE:"`, I believe. `^` means "start of string". You could also use `grepl` and then negating the expression (`my_data[!grepl(...), my_data$ColumnA]`).

Answer (score 4):

You could call `read.delim` with `comment.char = "*"`:

```
my_data <- read.delim(file.choose(), header = TRUE, sep = "", quote = "",
                      dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "*")
```

This will remove the final line when you are reading it in because it starts with `*`.

Another option is `fread` from `data.table`. `fread` has a fancy `autostart` feature which automagically drops lines without the expected number of columns:

```
library(data.table)
fread(file.choose())
```

Comment: If i had multiple lines to exclude, could i use the same approach during reading?

Comment: If there are multiple lines that all start with `*` they will be removed. But you can only supply one fixed `comment.char` string. So `##` will remove lines that start with `##`, but you can't use `(*|#)` or `c("*","#")` to remove lines that start with `*` or `#`.

Comment: One more thing to add, if you end up still having trouble, check out `fread` from `data.table`. It has very powerful features designed to just work in the vast majority of cases.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to handle this, which is to write a short function that takes the regexes that you want to filter out. You can feed it the file name, but if this is missing it will give you the file dialogue:

```r
read_broken <- function(file_path, filter_out = "^[*]NOTE:")
{
  if(missing(file_path)) file_path <- file.choose()
  x <- suppressWarnings(readLines(file_path))
  x <- x[nzchar(x)]
  x <- x[!apply(sapply(filter_out, grepl, x), 1, any)]
  read.delim(text = x, header = TRUE, sep = "", quote = "", dec = ".", fill = TRUE)
}
```

So you can do:

```
read_broken("myfile.txt")
#>   ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
#> 1      A2      17      14
#> 2      B2      20      -1
#> 3      C2      21      36
```

Or

```
read_broken("myfile.txt", filter_out = c("^[*]NOTE:", "A2"))
#>   ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
#> 1      B2      20      -1
#> 2      C2      21      36
```